# 2D array storage

Tags: php, arrays

Why it is the best practice to store your message or results in the two dimensional array?

I grilled it a lot in my mind but failed to produce an exact answer

The answers which came up to me with lot of grilling are as following :-

1. To store 2 messages at one time
2. To have the facility to store large messages
3. To store the large number of messages

though I am not sure about any one of them I admit it that my problem is not that programming oriented!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be best to look at what the PHP [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) have to say about arrays first:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
> associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
> different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
> table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
> queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
> and **multidimensional** arrays are also possible.

As you can see from that definition, php arrays are very flexible and cover a lot of use cases. The particular area you are asking about is the multidimensional(2D) PHP array style. Now take a look at how a creating a 2D array looks:

```
$blank2DArray = array(array());
```

It's fairly clear that what you have is simply an array of arrays, ie a 2d Array.

So where 2D arrays are useful are cases where you have data that goes beyond simple `key => value` usage. A simple example: You have some results from multiple race car drivers and their scores from a race course. Each driver has multiple pieces of information so you need more than just a single `key => value` stored for each driver. You could make an object with attributes to store with this kind of thing, but you could handle it very quickly and simply with a PHP 2D array like this:

```
$drivers = array();
$drivers[0] = array('driver_id' => 2, 'course_id' => 5 'score' => 61.6);
$drivers[1] = array('driver_id' => 3, 'course_id' => 4 'score' => 70.8);
$drivers[2] = array('driver_id' => 8, 'course_id' => 2 'score' => 76.8, 'winner' => 1);
```

Each driver and their data are represented by a new array and each is added with an index(this does not need to be numeric). Notice `driver[2]` has an attribute `winner` that the others do not have; this is allowed because PHP allows for *jagged arrays*, ie not all entries have to be the same size. You can easily access child elements of each array like this:

```
$drivers[0]['driver_id'] //prints 2
$drivers[1]['course_id'] //prints 4
$drivers[2]['score'] //prints 76.8
```

PHP arrays are excellent for solving a variety of problems and 2D arrays specifically allow for representing complex data far beyond simple `key => value` storage. For an in-depth look under the hood at PHP arrays check out this blog post: [Link](https://sheriframadan.com/2012/10/a-closer-look-into-php-arrays/)

So to answer your question it may not always be best practice to use a 2D array, it will depend on the problem you are trying to solve. PHP arrays are a swiss army knife and the 2D variety are excellent for solving problems where you need to store variable, complex data elements.

Comment: thanks for that scintillating reply now i can figure out which way to GO.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad so I'll cover the two possibilities that come to mind:

1 > You're looking for a way to have PHP access and use multidimensional arrays:

> ```
> $sData[0] = array("Name" => "T-Rex", "Type" => "dinosaur");
> $sData[1] = array("Name" => "Frog", "Type" => "amphibian");
> $sData[2] = array("Name" => "Salamander", "Type" => "amphibian);
> ```

This will allow you to have multiple rows with multiple sub-rows worth of data inside of them. There's no limit (besides machine memory) as to how many rows deep you can go.

2 > You're trying to figure out how to store that information in the database. In which case you need two tables like such:

> ```
> Table: types
> Structure: id INT(8) autoincrement, typename VARCHAR(65)
> Example Data: 0, dinosaur -- 1, amphibian
>
> Table: animals
> Structure: id INT(8) autoincrement, type_id INT(8), name VARCHAR(65)
> Example Data: 0, 0, T-Rex -- 1, 1, Frog -- 2, 1, Salamander
> ```

Comment: thanks Justin for the explanation. But i didn't really need that database part.